# How to store new items in localstorage or sessionstorage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage, session-storage

I am really new and total lame in javascript. I am trying to learn it but if you will see the code I made you'll probably facepalm yourself because of how I put html tags in the innerHTML >:D **anyway... to the problem.**

**I would like to built a chat without php (don't ask why).**

Without database I made a thing that if you click "**send message**" your message will only show until you refresh the page and I get an e-mail with the message (for later to add it inside the embed code; **yes it is dumb**).

[Here is an working example without local or sessionstorage (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFEhc.png)

[Here is a code without implemented the storage function(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8R1e.png)

However I would like to store the message from the user for at least one session. I was searching for some time and discover the sessionStorage. **Wow that is exactly what I needed**. But as I am extremely bad I am still getting the only one last input you put there

**[as you can see on this image here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2eRQ.png)**

And if I am not typing anything, like only open the chat on a new session **[I am getting the "null" message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0yIo.png)** Yes I understand that if there is no data inserted into a textbox I will get a result such as null... But I saw some people can make it that if there was no message inserted the null was hidden somewhere. And also that it can save newer messages aswell and store them.

**I would really be extremely thankful if someone can help me to figure this out... As I am extreme beginner... thank you guys, love you!**

Here is my lame *** code so take a laugh and then help me please ♥

```
var storeditem = localStorage.getItem("storeditem");

function pridat() {
                    
                    var item = document.sample.message.value;
                    var msg = document.sample.message.value;
    
                    var obal = document.createElement('div');
                    obal.setAttribute("class", "you");
    
                    var tr = obal.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
                    tr.setAttribute("class", "message");
    
                    var td1 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
                    td1.setAttribute("class", "text");
                    td1.textContent=msg;
                    localStorage.setItem("storeditem", item);
                    document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(obal);

                }

window.onload = function get(){
localStorage.getItem("storeditem");

document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = "<div class='message'><p class='text'>hey</p>
</div><div class='time'>13:28</div><div class='you'><div class='message'>
<p class='text'>" + storeditem + "</p></div></div>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns null of undefined if the storage is empty. So, you will need to add a call back function if the storage doesn't exist if it is a new chat like this:

```
var storeditem = localStorage.getItem("storeditem") || (function() {
  //add here the code you want for a new chat for example a welcome message
  return "This is the start of the chat";
})();

function pridat() {
    var item = document.sample.message.value;
    var msg = document.sample.message.value;
    var obal = document.createElement('div');
    obal.setAttribute("class", "you");
    
    var tr = obal.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    tr.setAttribute("class", "message");
    var td1 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    td1.setAttribute("class", "text");
    td1.textContent=msg;
    localStorage.setItem("storeditem", item);
    document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(obal);
}

window.onload = function get(){
localStorage.getItem("storeditem");

document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = "<div class='message'><p class='text'>hey</p>
</div><div class='time'>13:28</div><div class='you'><div class='message'>
<p class='text'>" + storeditem + "</p></div></div>";

}
```

I hope this helped:)

Comment: Hello, yes it was working but I am still suffering with the problem that the old messages are replacing with the new ones. I tried creating the arrays like anudeep told and that is currently working, but sadly I am lost again because I dont know how to put an html tag inside array that is getting data from textarea... for example display it like: document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = "div class='message'> " + value + "</div>"; ( in this case the value is data you entered to the textarea)

Answer (score 0):

I think you that the last message u sent overrides the message u send before in the localstorage. To overcome this you could store the messages as an array in local or session storage and iterate over them and render the messages in `window.onload()`

Comment: Hi, okay so I search for a bit and I created an array and it is working because anything I am typing into the textarea stays on the localstorage.  However I am now experiencing thing that I don't know  how to addd html tags there (divs with classes for bubble style chat)... Is it possible to add data to the array for something like: document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = "div class='message'>
" + value + "</div>";     ( in this case the value is data you entered to the textarea)

Comment: You can store the element itself as a string inside the array, but what I would recommend is to store elements as an array of objects, as it is easy to iterate through and render it.

Answer (score 0):

**GUYS somehow I fixed it** in the most dumbest way, but it is working :D I just put more IDs and create hidden input with value full of my html div classes ahaha :D it is so dumb but It is working ♥

I just wanted to thank you all for your help and solutions but sadly I am newbie and even tho I know your methods are working, I still can not understand them.

But I am showing you the code for fun how dumb I am :D :D

```
<input id="input" type="hidden" value="<div class='ochranaodpoved'><div class='spravickaty'><p class='textspravyty'>"/>
<textarea id="input2" name="message" placeholder="Write your message" rows="2" cols="35" style="resize: none; font-family:font1; font-size:15px;"></textarea>
<input id="input3" type="hidden" value="</p></div></div>" />
<button onclick="add()"> Send </button>
```

And the JS code here:

```js
function add() {
  var new_data = document.getElementById('input').value +
    document.getElementById('input2').value +
    document.getElementById('input3').value;

  if (sessionStorage.getItem('tabulka') == null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('tabulka', '[]');
  }

  var old_data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('tabulka'));
  old_data.push(new_data);

  sessionStorage.setItem('tabulka', JSON.stringify(old_data));
  document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('tabulka'));
}

function view() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('tabulka') != null) {
    document.getElementById('cet2').innerHTML = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('tabulka'));
  }
}
```

Once again, thank you for your help! :) this post is now solved! :)
Btw. I was trying to put `.querySelectorAll("#input, #input2", #input3");`
Instead of manually `.getElementById` but somehow it didn't work :/